# is it possible to call function from another process using QSharedMemory

Tags: c++, qt

I know it is possible to share variables through shared memory, is it possible to put a function pointer to a shared memory from process A and from process B get it and call as function?

I don't really find a specific answer to this question in docs.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Pointers are only meaningful in the address space of the process. You need some form of message passing to trigger the function call on the other side. To avoid bloat, you can do the following: Since Qt slots can be invoked dynamically (i.e. called by knowing their name as a string and their parameter types), you can pass a message to a dispatcher function that parses the message and [invokes](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) the slot dynamically.

Comment: So can I invoke process B's slot from process A?

Comment: Not directly, as I said. The dispatcher function I proposed runs in process B. Process A sends a message that describes the function call and the dispatcher does the actual call.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `sending a message` from A to B?

Comment: Sending a message is putting data into the shared memory or any other means of IPC (for example, sockets). You can either make up a protocol yourself (which defines the format of the messages) or use an existing one, for example JSON-RPC. If you only have a handful of functions to call, implementing this might be an overkill: you might be better off with just a switch-case and identifying your functions by numbers. The idea I proposed is much more flexible and scalable but might not worth it in your case.

Comment: @Tamás Szelei: JSON-RPC seems like a bad idea for shared memory. Even for local IPC through sockets, I think it's overkill. A better idea might be a binary protocol like Google's Protocol Buffers.

Comment: I think the protocol is secondary, because after you parse the message you need to do the same thing whichever protocol you chose. Protobuf frees you from parsing at the cost of code generation (but a json message can be parsed with a library equally easily). On the other hand, protobuf is not a RPC protocol, only a means for serializing it, so one would have to make one up still. I also assumed that an RPC solution can be overkill for simple cases, but I don't know the OP's use case, so it might be a good idea.